# merging arrays without generating keys

Tags: php, arrays

How do I merge 2 arrays into `$array3`

```
$array1 = array('first', 'second');
$array2 = array('third', 'fourth');

$array3 = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
```

All the functions I'm finding add keys that turn it into an associative array [0]=>'first'. I don't want this. I want it to stay as a string only array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array do *always* have an index/key but they can be omitted when using the [`array()` language constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.array-func):

> If a key is not specified for a value, the maximum of the integer indices is taken and the new key will be that value plus 1.

So `array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth')` is the same as `array(0 => 'first', 1 => 'second', 2 => 'third', 3 => 'fourth')`:

```
$a = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
$b = array(0 => 'first', 1 => 'second', 2 => 'third', 3 => 'fourth');
var_dump($a === $b);  // bool(true)
var_dump(var_export($a, true) === var_export($b, true));  // bool(true)
```

So just use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Doc: http://php.net/array_merge

The [0], [1] etc. keys are the default keys of your array - every array has them.

Comment: Indeed, for people coming from other languages this may be confusing, but the first sentence in [the manual on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) says it all: _'An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. '_

Answer (score 1):

You have always keys with your elements. Try this:

```
print_r( $array1 );
```

And you will see [0] => "first"

It's not a problem with a function you use to merge - keys simple always exists.
Probaly you are looking for solution in bad way - do not search how to get rid of indexes, but try to rewrite your solution in way, where indexes will do not have any meaning.